# Cosmos DB IQueryable on nullable fields

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have this field in my model:

```
public class Lead {
   ....
   public Guid? ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to filter on this field using `IQueryable` in the code like this

```
var queryable = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Lead>()
            .OrderBy(l => l.Created)
            .AsQueryable();
....
//Use a list of GUIDs to filter on
if (search.ClientId?.Any() == true)
{
   queryable = queryable.Where(lead => lead.ClientId.HasValue && search.ClientId.Contains(lead.ClientId.Value));
}
return queryable;
```

I expect this to add following `WHERE` clause when translated to SQL

```
WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.clientId) AND c.clientId IN ('some GUID', 'another GUID', 'and so on')
```

In practice this LINQ statement becomes this

```
SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE (root['clientId']['hasValue'] AND (root['clientId']['value'] IN ('e870a235-ccb0-4a78-81b3-05dce5ac8a7f'))) ORDER BY root['created'] ASC
```

When I run the code, the query doesn't return any object when run even though there are documents with the specified GUID in the field in the container. My project is using the latest version of Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos (3.23.0) as far as I can see in Nuget package manager.

What am I doing wrong in my C# code? Is there any way to get this working?

Comment: What is your problem with the generated LINQ query? Are your list of guids not appearing in the IN statement? Any particular reason you want to use IS_DEFINED instead of the approach that was used?

Comment: @jegtugado, the problem is that the query doen't return any object when run even though there are documents with the specified GUID in the field in the container. And as you can see, the generated SQL is totally incorrect since it assumes that there are `hasValue` and `value` fields which is not the case.

Comment: This kind of issue is really hard to figure out. I would recommend running the generated query to Cosmos DB directly to see if there are any result. A rough guess on my part is converting `lead => lead.ClientId.HasValue && search.ClientId.Contains(lead.ClientId.Value)` to `lead => lead.ClientId.HasValue && search.ClientId.Any(s => s == lead.ClientId.Value)`. Good luck.

Comment: @jegtugado, thanks, I will try that.

Comment: @jegtugado, I got this exception when I tried with `Any`: 
"Input is not of type IDocumentQuery., Windows/10.0.19043 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.23.1"

Comment: Shouldn't your this line of code `queryable = queryable.Where(lead => lead.ClientId.HasValue && search.ClientId.Contains(lead.ClientId.Value));` be `queryable = queryable.Where(lead => lead.ClientId.HasValue && lead.ClientId.Contains(search.ClientId.Value));`?

Comment: @GauravMantri, no, because my method gets a list of GUIDs to filter on. The code should check if lead's client id is in the given list.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by casting to `Guid` in the `Where` clause:

```
if (search.ClientId?.Any() == true)
{
    queryable = queryable.Where(lead => search.ClientId.Contains((Guid)lead.LeadRequest.ClientId));
}
```